# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int. In python, when I add some inputs and some function have to use it

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, typeerror, dijkstra

Im new at coding and I'm doing a code for algorithms with a request matrix. I'm seeing this error when I add the code with the ***.

Context: I'm doing an input menu with options so the user can with number 1 create a matrix in excel and so python read it. With number 2 now I want to implement Dijkstra Algorithm.

I had search about this type of error and I know that happen because I'm putting a int and not a str, but I can't find the way to change it and so can read my dijkstra algorithm function requesting the initial node and the goal node.

Maybe I have some error in the parameters or variables. I'm not too good with functions calling. (Just starting to code)

```
import openpyxl as opxl
import sys

cant_nodos = 3

# FUNCIONES


## Crea la cantidad de nodos a utilizar y la restricción de un mínimo de nodos.

def min_nodos():
    cant_nodos = int(input("Ingresar cantidad de nodos a utilizar (mínimo 6)"))
    while(cant_nodos < 6):
        print("ERROR: Elija mínimo 6 nodos y que sea entero positivo. ")
        cant_nodos = int(input("Ingresar cantidad de nodos a utilizar (mínimo 6)"))
    return cant_nodos
 

## Crea un menu
    
def crear_menu():
    menu=int(input("Elija una opción \n 1.Crear parámetros \n 2.Aplicar Dijkstra \n 3.Aplicar Kruskal \n 4.Salir"))
    if menu == 1:
        min_nodos()
    elif menu == 2: 
        *** empezar = str(input("Elija un nodo de inicio: "))
        terminar = str(input("Elija un nodo de termino: ")) ***
        dijkstra(cant_nodos, empezar, terminar)
    elif menu == 3:
        kruskal()
    elif menu == 4:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("\n ERROR: Elija una opción válida.")
        crear_menu()
        
    
## Crea la matriz en excel
        
def crear_matriz_adyacente(cant_nodos):
    libro = opxl.Workbook()
    pagina = libro.active
    pagina.title = "matriz_de_adyacencia"
    lista_nodos = []
    cont = 0
    
    while(cont < cant_nodos):
        contador = str(cont+1)
        nodo = str(input("Ingrese nodo " +contador+ ":"))
        if nodo not in lista_nodos:
            lista_nodos.append(nodo)
            pagina.cell(row = 1, column = cont+2, value = nodo)
            pagina.cell(row = cont+2, column = 1, value = nodo)
            cont = cont+1
        else:
            print("ERROR: Nodo existente, escoja otro: ")
            
    
    for fila in range(len(lista_nodos)):
        for columna in range(len(lista_nodos)):
            if fila == columna:
                valor = 0
            elif columna > fila:
                valor = int(input("Ingrese valor de nodo " +lista_nodos[fila]+" con el nodo " +lista_nodos[columna]+ ":")) 
                      
            while(valor < 0):
                print("ERROR: Valor negativo. Ingrese un valor positivo")
                valor = int(input("Ingrese valor de nodo " +lista_nodos[fila]+" con el nodo " +lista_nodos[columna]+ ":"))
            
            pagina.cell(row = fila+2, column = columna+2, value = valor)
            pagina.cell(row = columna+2, column = fila+2, value = valor)
            
    libro.save("matriz_adyacente.xlsx")
    
    return crear_menu()


## Abre la matriz para utilizarla

def abrir_matriz_adyacente(matriz_adyacente):
    excel = opxl.load_workbook(matriz_adyacente)
    lista_excel = []
    pagina = excel.active
    maximo_columna = pagina.max_column
    maximo_fila = pagina.max_row
    
    for fila in range(1, maximo_fila+1):
        lista_fila = []
        for columna in range(1, maximo_columna+1):
            espacio = pagina.cell(row = fila, column = columna)
            lista_fila.append(espacio.value)
        lista_excel.append(lista_fila)
        
    return lista_excel

def dijkstra(cant_nodos, empezar, terminar):
    lista_excel = abrir_matriz_adyacente(cant_nodos)
    camino_mas_corto = {}
    pista_predecedor = {}
    nodos_no_explorados = lista_excel
    inf = 9999999
    pista_camino = []
    
    for nodo in nodos_no_explorados:
        camino_mas_corto[nodo] = inf
        
    camino_mas_corto[empezar] = 0
    
    while nodos_no_explorados:
        nodo_min_distancia = None
        
        for nodo in nodos_no_explorados:
            if nodo_min_distancia is None:
                nodo_min_distancia = nodo
            elif camino_mas_corto[nodo] < camino_mas_corto[nodo_min_distancia]:
                nodo_min_distancia = nodo
        
        opciones_caminos = lista_excel[nodo_min_distancia].items()
        
        for nodo_hijo, peso in opciones_caminos:
            
            if peso + camino_mas_corto[nodo_min_distancia] < camino_mas_corto[nodo_hijo]:
                camino_mas_corto[nodo_hijo] = peso + camino_mas_corto[nodo_min_distancia]
                pista_predecedor[nodo_hijo] = nodo_min_distancia
                
        nodos_no_explorados.pop(nodo_min_distancia)
        
    nodo_actual = terminar
    
    while nodo_actual != empezar:
        try:
            pista_camino.insert(0, nodo_actual)
            nodo_actual = pista_predecedor[nodo_actual]
                        
        except KeyError:
            print("El camino no existe")
            break
    
    pista_camino(0, empezar)
    
    if camino_mas_corto[terminar] != inf:
        print("Distancia más corta es: " + str(camino_mas_corto[terminar]))
        print("Camino optimo es: " + str(pista_camino))
    


crear_menu()
crear_matriz_adyacente(cant_nodos)
lista_excel = abrir_matriz_adyacente("matriz_adyacente.xlsx")
print(lista_excel)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Include the full stacktrace, please.  There's one specific spot in your program where you're passing an int instead of a str, but without the stacktrace it's hard to guess what line that might be.

Comment: file... line 157 in <module> crear_matriz_adyacente(cant_nodos)    file... line 85 in crear_matriz_adyacente return crear_menu()      line 38  crear_menu dijkstra(cant_nodos, empezar, terminar)    file line 107 dijkstra lista_excel = abrir_matriz_adyacente excel = opxl.load_workbook reader = excelreader(filename, read_only, keep_vba)   line 124 __init__ self.archive = validate_archive(fn).    line 78 in __validate_archive file_format = os.path.splittext File , line 118, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int.       (You mean this?)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```py
lista_excel = abrir_matriz_adyacente(cant_nodos) # cant_nodos = 3
```

which calls

```py
excel = opxl.load_workbook(matriz_adyacente) # matriz_adyacente = cant_nodos = 3
```

`opxl.load_workbook` expects string/bytes as an argument, not an int. Your program isn't that straightforward to understand, so I'm not sure why you're passing an `int` to the function. Just replace it with the filename of the sheet that you want to open.